# Cannot resolve symbol GeoDataClient and AutoCompletePredictionBuffer

Tags: android

My whole app.gradle dependency codes:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "rjj.manilapuvtravelcompanion_2nd"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+'
    compile 'com.weiwangcn.betterspinner:library-material:1.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

I'm still getting red on the AutoCompletePredictionBufferResponse and GeoDataClient. What am I missing? I'm following the tutorial in this link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Trdd9EnmqY but when I copied the whole code in GitHub in the PlaceAutoCompleteAdapter part, I'm getting those two reds.

```
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompletePredictionBufferResponse;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.GeoDataClient;
```

Comment: Did get the wrong code from Github?. I follow the link in youtube link you give, and no import AutocompletePredictionBufferResponse found.

Comment: Are you sure? I'll go check again.

Answer (score 0):

'compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.0' this will fix the bug